# YouTube duplicated video id

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to find out via YouTube API or other method, that if an uploaded video is rejected for duplication, what is the "Duplicate video ID", that I can see in Video manager?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

The YouTube API exposes a `status.rejectionReason` String which will return `duplicate` if the video already exists on your channel.

Unfortunately, the API doesn't expose what the duplicate video actually is.  That is something you will need to go into your Video Manager and check manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I do to find out if a video is rejected for duplication. Right now, I am looking for a way to identify the duplicated video id via script.

Comment: @Zoltan have  you found the way to find out video id?

Comment: Unfortunately not.